# Colocar tfoot al final del documento PDF con Playwright y AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, adonisjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto utilizando AdonisJS y Playwright para generar un PDF a partir de una tabla HTML. Necesito colocar el `tfoot` de la tabla como footer en el PDF. Sin embargo, no quiero que el footer se repita en cada página, y por lo tanto, no estoy utilizando `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` ya que eso resultaría en la repetición del footer en cada página.

Estoy bastante sorprendida, porque busque por todos lados, probe pagedJS, evaluate DOM con playwright, estilos css como flexbox, posicionamiento absoluto y grid pero no logro empujar el tfoot / footer al final de la ultima pagina. Incluso encontre un foro en github donde solicitaban esto a playwright de ya hace bastante y no hay solucion. Tal vez implementarlo en la libreria llevaria varias complicaciones.

Ya he resuelto que el footer aparezca solo en la última página con algo de javascript, pero mi desafío actual es empujar el `tfoot` al final del documento sin utilizar posicionamiento fijo.

Aquí está la estructura general de mi HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Signature fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mali&family=Mrs+Saint+Delafield&family=The+Nautigal&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
    {{--  @vite(['resources/css/facturaRecibo.css'])  --}}
</head>

<body id="someSelector">

    <div id="container" class="m-5 flex flex-col text-xs">

        <table class="w-full">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="mt-1 flex-1 text-center text-base">
                            <b>
                                @each(FormasdePago in FormasPago)
                                {{isset(FormasdePago?.NombreFormaPago) ? FormasdePago?.NombreFormaPago : ' '}}
                                @if(!$loop?.last)
                                ,
                                @endif
                                @endeach
                            </b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center text-base">
                            <b># <span>{{isset(NumeroOrdenReporte) ? NumeroOrdenReporte : ' '}}</span></b>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="miTbody">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="tbodyContainer">

                            <div class="pt-3 table-formulario">
                                <table class="table-card border-collapse w-full">
                                    <tbody class="table-card-body">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2">
                                                <b># Factura:</b>
                                                <span>{{isset(NumeroFactura) ? NumeroFactura : ' '}}</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2">
                                                <b>Fecha:</b>
                                                <span>{{isset(GeneradaEn) ? GeneradaEn : ' '}}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2">
                                                <b>Cliente:</b>
                                                <span>{{isset(GeneradaEn) ? NombreCliente : ' '}}</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2">
                                                <b>RTN Cliente:</b>
                                                <span>{{isset(RTNCliente) ? RTNCliente : ' '}}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2"
                                                class="border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-center">
                                                <b>Generada por:</b>
                                                <span>{{isset(GeneradaPor) ? GeneradaPor : ' '}}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <table class="mt-4 table-card border-collapse w-full">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="min-w-[9rem] max-w-[9rem] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-start">
                                                Producto</th>
                                            <th class="max-w-[20px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-center">Cantidad</th>
                                            <th class="max-w-[35px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-center">Precio</th>
                                            <th class="max-w-[35px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-center">Total</th>
                                        </tr> 
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="table-card-body">
                                        @each(DetalledeFactura in DetalleFactura)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="max-w-[9rem] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2">
                                                @if(DetalledeFactura.ValorDescuento)
                                                *
                                                @endif
                                                {{DetalledeFactura?.NombreProducto}}
                                                @if(DetalledeFactura?.Variacion)
                                                <div class="text-start"> {{isset(DetalledeFactura?.Variacion?.NombreVariacion) ? DetalledeFactura?.Variacion?.NombreVariacion : ' '}}</div>
                                                @endif
                                                @each(ListdeCombinados in DetalledeFactura?.ListCombinados)
                                                <div class="flex-1 text-start italic pl-4">-{{isset(ListdeCombinados.NombreProducto) ? ListdeCombinados.NombreProducto : ' '}}
                                                    <b>x{{ListdeCombinados.Cantidad}}</b>
                                                </div>
                                                @endeach
                                            <td class="max-w-[20px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-center">
                                                {{isset(DetalledeFactura?.Cantidad) ? DetalledeFactura?.Cantidad : ' '}}</td>
                                            <td class="max-w-[35px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-end">{{SimboloMoneda}}
                                                {{twoDigits(DetalledeFactura?.PrecioVenta)}}</td>
                                            <td class="max-w-[35px] border border-solid border-slate-900 px-2 text-end">{{SimboloMoneda}}
                                                {{unitTotal(DetalledeFactura?.PrecioVenta, DetalledeFactura?.Cantidad)}}</td>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            @if(Anulada)
                            <div class="flex">
                                <b class="flex-1 text-center my-2 text-lg uppercase text-red-700">Anulada</b>
                            </div>
                            @endif

                            <div
                            class="mt-5 flex gap-3 border-0 border-b-2 border-solid border-slate-900 sm:pb-2">
                                <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-4">
                                    <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-3">
                                        <div>
                                            <b>No. Correl. O/C Exenta:</b>
                                            <span></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>No. Correl. Exonerado:</b>
                                            <span></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>No. Correl. S.A.G:</b>
                                            <span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="">SON: {{isset(TotalEnLetras) ? TotalEnLetras : ' '}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex w-2/5 min-w-[40%] flex-col">
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Subtotal:</span>
                                        <span class="flex w-2/5 min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(SubTotal)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Exento:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(Exento)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Gravado:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(Gravado)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Descuentos Exentos:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(DescuentoExento)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Descuentos Gravados:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(Descuento)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Subtotal con Descuento:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(SubTotalConDescuentos)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">ISV 15%:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(Imp15)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">ISV 18%:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(Imp18)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">Propina:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(TotalPropina)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <b class="flex-1">TOTAL A PAGAR:</b>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}}</span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(TotalFactura)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @if(IncluyeDescuento)
                            <div class="mt-5 text-xs">
                                <span>* con descuento aplicado</span>
                            </div>
                            @endif

                            @if(IncluyeDescuento)
                            <div class="mt-5 text-xs">
                                <span>* con descuento aplicado</span>
                            </div>        
                            @endif

                            @if(Anulada)
                            <div class="flex">
                                <b class="flex-1 text-center my-2 text-lg uppercase text-red-700">Anulada</b>
                            </div>        
                            @endif

                            <div class="mt-2 flex gap-3">
                                <div class="flex-1"></div>
                                <div class="min-w-[40%]">
                                    @each(FormasdePago in FormasPago)
                                    <div class="flex">
                                        <span class="flex-1">{{isset(FormasdePago?.NombreFormaPago) ? FormasdePago?.NombreFormaPago : ' '}}:</span>
                                        <span class="flex min-w-[40%]">
                                            <span class="m-auto min-w-[28%] text-start">{{SimboloMoneda}} </span>
                                            <span class="m-auto flex-1 text-end">{{twoDigits(FormasdePago?.Valor)}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>                
                                    @endeach
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-8 flex w-full">
                                <div class="w-3/5 flex-initial">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>Original al:</b>
                                            <span>Cliente</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>Copia al:</b>
                                            <span> Obligado Triburario Emisor</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="min-w-[40%]">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>Rango Autorizado:</b>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>{{isset(RangoAutorizado) ? RangoAutorizado : ' '}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-2 flex">
                                <div class="flex-1"></div>
                                <div class="min-w-[40%]">
                                    <div>
                                        <b>Fecha Límite Emisión:</b>
                                        <span>{{isset(FechaLimiteEmision) ? FechaLimiteEmision : ' '}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @if(PuntosLealtad)
                            <div class="mt-5 text-center">
                                Puntos ganados: <b>{{isset(PuntosLealtad?.TotalPuntosGanados) ? PuntosLealtad?.TotalPuntosGanados : ' '}}</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                Puntos canjeados: <b>{{isset(PuntosLealtad.TotalPuntosCanjeados) ? PuntosLealtad.TotalPuntosCanjeados : ' '}}</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                Puntos disponibles: <b>{{isset(PuntosLealtad.TotalPuntosDisponibles) ? PuntosLealtad.TotalPuntosDisponibles : ''}}</b>
                            </div>       
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot id="miTfoot">
                <tr>
                    <td>Yalo</td>
                  </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Y aquí está el CSS que estoy utilizando actualmente:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
}

.table-formulario,
.table-formulario tbody {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.table-card-body td,
.table-card-body tr {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.table-card {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

La configuracion de los margenes del pdf con playwright

```
const optionsPdfConfig = {
  format: 'A4',
  margin: {
    top: '220px',
    right: '25px',
    bottom: '0',
    left: '25px',
  },
  headerTemplate: headerHtml,
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  printBackground: true,
}
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia sobre cómo puedo lograr esto de manera más efectiva sin utilizar `position: fixed`